# Table in list element causing line break

Tags: javascript, html-lists, html-table

I have a simple snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>construct</td>
                <td>
                    <button>-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thing is, when viewed in chrome the `<li>` is displayed over 2 lines instead of one.

There seems to be a new line/line break added to the `<li>` before the `<table>` tag so instead of displaying:

```
* <table>
```

It displays:

```
*
<table>
```

If that makes sense?!

I've tried numerous display style combo's and can't seem to find out why this is happening? I know it is to do with the indent marker/list-style as when removed, `list-style-type:none`, the `<li>` will display correctly on 1 line, but I can't get it to work when using indent markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the rule below to your css styling for your table (I advise to use an id or class to your tag to differentiate it from other table elements)

```
table {
  display:inline-table;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

Demo below

```css
table {
  display:inline-table;
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><table>
            <tr>
                <td>construct</td>
                <td>
                    <button>-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**NB: tested in chromium Version 49.0.2623.108**

Answer (score 0):

Default Table styling has a linebreak preceeding it, you can use CSS to override it.

```
table {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Note that there are differences between `display: inline-block;` and `display: inline-table;` but for simple styling it will appear to have the same effect.

[CSS Display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
[CSS Vertical-Align Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: Ok so you've hit the nail on the head: **"Default Table styling has a linebreak preceeding it"**... now we just need a better way to remove it, as the method suggested leaves the list with bad positioning of the mark and table...

Comment: Sorry it looks like I hadn't tested multiple rows, like what @repzero had said, using the `vertical-align:text-top;` css attribute you should be able to fix the issues you are seeing with the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, as always... couldn't have done it without yz!

Here's what I'm gonna stick in my universal css file:

```
li > table{
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

There are 5 usable vert's:

1, top.
2, text-top.
3, middle.
4, bottom.
5, text-bottom.

Though [1 & 2] & [4 & 5] are virtually the same, each will align the **table & marker** relative to the `<li>`.